combine SQL queries
I have multiple queries to get data marked under different categories, with it returning the last X rows from before a given datetime. The max timestamp value will be different for each of the categories
SELECT * FROM table WHERE category="a" AND timestampCol < timestampValue1 ORDER BY timestampCol DESC LIMIT 3;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE category="b" AND timestampCol < timestampValue2 ORDER BY timestampCol DESC LIMIT 3;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE category="c" AND timestampCol < timestampValue3 ORDER BY timestampCol DESC LIMIT 3;
...

I would like to optimise this to run as a single query as it can be pulling from up to 8 categories at a time which is a lot of queries to be running.
I need the database to return a set number from each category. It would be nice to customize the LIMIT per category however this is not essential as long as I am guaranteed to have data return from all the categories.
I tried the query below, which will return the first 9 rows. But they  could all be from category A, which is not what I want.
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
 (category="a" AND timestampCol < timestampValue1)
 OR (category="b" AND timestampCol < timestampValue2)
 OR (category="c" AND timestampCol < timestampValue3)
ORDER BY timestampCol DESC LIMIT 9;
...

Using GROUP BY on category would only return me one of each category instead of 3, unless there is a nice way I can get that to work?
How can I do this?

take your first snippet there and put union between the queries?

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/restrict-results-to-top-n-rows-per-group

What version of MariaDB? The best solution here will use the row_number() window function, which requires at least MariaDB 10.2.

.. LIMIT 9 If some of the separate query returns less then 3 rows (for example, only 2 rows matches the criteria) then do you need to receive less than 9 total rows? or you need in 9 rows strictly, and in the above case you need to obtain more than 3 rows from another separate query?

Add row_number() window function to your query, partition by category:
select *
from
(
  SELECT t.*,
         row_number() over (partition by category order by timestampCol DESC) rn
  FROM table t
  WHERE (category="a" AND timestampCol < timestampValue1)
     OR (category="b" AND timestampCol < timestampValue2)
     OR (category="c" AND timestampCol < timestampValue3)
) dt
where rn <= 3
order by category, timestampCol DESC


( SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE category="a" AND ts < 'ts1' ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 3 )
UNION ALL
( SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE category="b" AND ts < 'ts2' ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 3 )
UNION ALL
( SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE category="c" AND ts < 'ts3' ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 3 )
ORDER By ts desc

AND have
INDEX(category, ts)

Analysis:

There is no need for a trailing LIMIT 9.  However, if you wanted only 3 results, then a trailing LIMIT 3 would be needed.
Each subquery will make good use of the index.  That is, performance will be rather good despite the number of subqueries.
I don't think using ( SELECT id ... ) and ending with a JOIN to get * will be beneficial.
Customing the LIMIT amounts should not impact performance.
Although there will be no parallel execution, having all the subqueries in a single, big, query is not too bad.
If you don't need the final ORDER BY ts, drop it -- this should avoid a temp table and sort at the end.


Did I miss a requirement?  What is the downvote about?

Not sure... but probably it seems like getting away from a separate SELECT for each category was the whole point of the question. Again: not my vote, though I suspect it's partly my fault in that my answer/edits put this to the top of the recent list again.

It wasnt my downvote, but I was ideally hoping for a non-union approach, though I am going to do some benchmarking when I get the chance on all the answers provided

@LavaTheif - You have several requirements (or at least desires); I don't see a way to achieve all of them in a single SELECT.

row_number() with a partition by clause on the category is your best option here, and it's not close.
Once we know to use row_number(), there are a number of ways we could adapt to do it. For this answer, I chose to introduce a table value constructor inside a CTE for mapping timestampValue columns, since I suspect this part of the data is different than presented in the original question, and for another reason that will become clear in a few moments:
WITH CategoryMap(category, timestamp) As (values 
    ('a', '<timestamp 1 here>'),
    ('b', '<timestamp 2 here>'),
    ('c', '<timestamp 3 here>')
    -- if these timestamps are in a table, you could use a query here to find them 
)
, numbered AS (
    SELECT * 
        , row_number() over (partition by t.category order by t.timestampCol desc) rn
    FROM table t
    INNER JOIN CategoryMap cm ON cm.category = t.category
        AND t.timestampCol < cm.timestamp
)
SELECT *
FROM numbered
WHERE rn <= 3

That should work for the basic requirement. It also has the nice property of no OR or UNION, which should help it do very well with index use, especially if the CategoryMap data can be pulled from an indexed table.
But I also see this:

It would be nice to customize the LIMIT per category

We can extend the mapping to do this, and even provide a default 3 if there is no entry
WITH CategoryMap(category, timestamp, maxrows) As (values 
    ('a', '<timestamp 1 here>', 4),
    ('b', '<timestamp 2 here>', 2),
    ('c', '<timestamp 3 here>', NULL) -- use a default for max rows
)
, numbered AS (
    SELECT * 
        , row_number() over (partition by t.category order by t.timestampCol desc) rn
    FROM table t
    INNER JOIN CategoryMap cm ON cm.category = t.category
        AND t.timestampCol < cm.timestamp
)
SELECT *
FROM numbered
WHERE rn <= coalesce(maxrows, 3)

Of course, you'll want to use an actual column list instead of just SELECT *, if for no other reason than removing the mapping and rn columns from the final result (it's good practice to do this anyway).
This should work in supported versions of MariaDB. If your database is too old for windowing functions or table value constructors, that's a problem, because your database no longer gets security patches, which would be a BIG DEAL.
